# PHP: how to loop through a mulit-dimensional array and output the subarrays instead of the elements of the subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

Its my first question here, because I usually find what I am looking for, but here I am lost.

I created a multidimensional array the following way:

Here is the code - from Input to the push:

This is the input into the textarea:

```
VIE-CAI
HAV-VRA
JFK-SYD
```

Here I am fetching the data from the text area on click, after an enter a new element should be created with the string of destinations:

```
$textarea = $_POST['many_destinations'];
$textarea = str_replace(' ', '', $textarea);
$textarea = strtoupper($textarea);
$textarea =  preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", $textarea);
```

Now I am "exploding" these strings to elements of an array. Storing them in the main array $textarea_new

```
 foreach($textarea as $row) {
      $routes = explode('-', $row);
      array_push($textarea_new, $routes);
  }
```

At the beginning of the whole click function I declared this array as:

```
$textarea_new = array();
```

so right now I would expect it to look like this:

```
$textarea_new = array
      (
      array("VIE","CAI"),
      array("HAV","VRA"),
      array("JFK","SYD")
      );
```

EDIT: from your comments I can assume that it doesnt look like this, because you didnt face any problems with the following loop:

Now I want to loop through each route (subarray) and output it, so that i can handle each subarray seperately.

One of the most suggested things I found on stackoverflowwas the following, but it gave me really strange results:

```
foreach ($textarea_new as $route) {
        if (is_array($route)){
            foreach($route as $destination){
                echo $destination." ";

            }
        } 
    }
```

The output for the function above is the following:
VIE CAI HAV VRA JFK SYD VIE CAI HAV VRA JFK SYD VIE CAI HAV VRA JFK SYD

but it should actually just be:

VIE CAI HAV VRA JFK SYD

Please tell me if you need more info and especially if this is not the right way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Give a rough example of the array

Comment: Can you tell me the output you want to get?

Comment: Please proper format your question it is very confusing. It would be easily understandable in one time reading.

Comment: can you show proper array example for this `main array $textarea_new and output every subarray`

Comment: i added it above in my post :)

Comment: I have gone through the example code you have provided, and it gave the output exactly as you want `VIE CAI HAV VRA JFK SYD`. What is you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your foreach code is working it is giving output `VIE CAI HAV VRA JFK SYD`

Comment: so probably i didnt create the array properly...
could you check my code for pushing the new arrays into the main array?
thank you!

Comment: I solved it now... i used a lot of arrays in my code and since Ali Niaz and Omi told me that he got the right result I checked these loops again and found out that I had to redesign them. Thank you!
How can I rate you now?

Answer (score 0):

The only real preparation that seems necessary is to, first, set all letters to uppercase.  Beyond that, just write a regex pattern that validates and extracts in one step, then you can loop the results.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/r8HBa)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8On0Q/1))

```
$flightpaths = 'VIE-CAI
hav-vra
JFK-SYD';

if (!preg_match_all('~^([A-Z]{3})-([A-Z]{3})$~m', strtoupper($flightpaths), $out, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    echo 'Invalid Entry';
} else {
    foreach ($out as $row) {
        echo "Destination #1: {$row[1]}\n";
        echo "Destination #2: {$row[2]}\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Destination #1: VIE
Destination #2: CAI

Destination #1: HAV
Destination #2: VRA

Destination #1: JFK
Destination #2: SYD
```